# spark-shell scale Filter timestamp column, take average of exchange rate and aggregate on date

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df as follows,

```
INSERTTIME,EXCAHNGERATE,CURRENCY
2021-01-01 00:01:38,0.731422,GBP
2021-01-01 00:00:57,0.731422,GBP
2021-01-01 00:01:38,0.731422,EUR
2021-01-01 00:00:57,0.731422,EUR
2021-01-02 00:00:18,0.731368,GBP
2021-01-03 00:00:31,0.731368,GBP
2021-01-03 00:00:06,0.731368,GBP
2021-01-02 00:00:26,0.731368,GBP
2021-01-04 00:00:48,0.730922,GBP
2021-01-04 00:04:46,0.730922,GBP
```

I want to remove the time and take average of the one day

**Desired output**

```
INSERTTIME,EXCAHNGERATE,CURRENCY
2021-01-01,0.731422,GBP
2021-01-01,0.731422,EUR
2021-01-02,0.731368,GBP
2021-01-03,0.731368,GBP
2021-01-04,0.730922,GBP
```

**My Idea**
I can do it in bash but I want to do it in spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the time (cast to a date) and currency:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy($"CURRENCY",$"INSERTTIME".cast("date").as("INSERTTIME"))
            .agg(mean("EXCAHNGERATE").alias("EXCAHNGERATE"))
            .orderBy("INSERTTIME")

df2.show
+--------+----------+------------+
|CURRENCY|INSERTTIME|EXCAHNGERATE|
+--------+----------+------------+
|     GBP|2021-01-01|    0.731422|
|     EUR|2021-01-01|    0.731422|
|     GBP|2021-01-02|    0.731368|
|     GBP|2021-01-03|    0.731368|
|     GBP|2021-01-04|    0.730922|
+--------+----------+------------+
```